# Logging presto queries on grafana dashboard using event-listener and fluent-bit

Tags: kubernetes, presto, fluentd, fluent-bit

I have a presto instance running on a namespace and it has a custom plugin and event-listener configured that gets all the logs and forwards them to 24224 port.

I can see the logs if they are written as log.info("any string here") but fluency.emit(tag, map<>) is not working at all and i dont see any logs or event object being sent to fluentd instance.

can you please help in configuring how it can work or how i can debug this when on AWS EKS?

When I check the logs of daemonset fluentbit, I can see it is listening to TCP port 24224

```
[input:forward:forward.0] listening on 0.0.0.0:24224
```

Here is the configuration of fluent-bit:

```
fluent-bit.conf: |-
    [SERVICE]
        HTTP_Server    On
        HTTP_Listen    0.0.0.0
        HTTP_PORT      2020
        Flush          10
        Daemon         Off
        Log_Level      trace
  
    [INPUT]
        Name           forward
        Port           24224
        Listen         0.0.0.0
    
    [Output]
        Name grafana-loki
        Match *
        Url <MY LOKI URL HERE>
        TenantID ""
        BatchWait 1
        BatchSize 1048576
        Labels {job="fluent-bit"}
        RemoveKeys kubernetes,stream
        AutoKubernetesLabels false
        LineFormat json
        LogLevel warn
  labelmap.json: |-
    {
      "kubernetes": {
        "container_name": "container",
        "host": "node",
        "labels": {
          "app": "app",
          "release": "release"
        },
        "namespace_name": "namespace",
        "pod_name": "instance"
      },
      "stream": "stream"
    }
```

Here is my event-listener.properties file contents from presto:

```
event-listener.name=presto-fluent-logger
event-listener.fluentd-host=127.0.0.1
event-listener.fluentd-port=24224
event-listener.fluentd-tag=presto.query
```

and I have followed all the steps from this link: [https://github.com/komamitsu/fluency](https://github.com/komamitsu/fluency/issues/183)

I am getting error in plugin **ConnectionException: Connection Refused**

I am sure that the presto plugin has got registered successfully and the error shows that it is not able to connect to my fluentbit instance may be. Not sure what host:port I should keep in plugin or event-listener.properties file

But I get no logs when I execute a query from presto cli. Can anyone please help?
I am not very sure what all codes do I need to place here

Comment: The problem can be here: `event-listener.fluentd-host=127.0.0.1`, if those two are in different pods. Can you create a service for the fluentd daemonset and try changing `event-listener.fluentd-host` to that name?

Comment: I did that. The problems were mutliple actually. 1 is the thing that you pointed. The other is not sure why but i have to set "AutoKubernetesLabels" value to true. Otherwise i dont get logs from presto plugin. Also the logs are coming in grafana but the entire hashmap is coming instead of json format.

Comment: Glad it helped. You probably know that but just in case - the service I suggested is a temporary measure to test the theory, don't leave it like that. You need to think of some other way to connect those two (maybe a unix-socket over hostPath volume). As for the `AutoKubernetesLabels` and the format problem - I have no idea, not familiar with fluentd.